# How long can a XMPP Session last?

Tags: session, timeout, xmpp

Without timeout? Or is there even a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on the lifetime of a connected jid. For command line bots, it is a good practice to send periodic ping packets to the server, just to make sure opened socket doesn't drop after some period of inactivity.

In case your client is connected from browser and suppose the user refreshes the browser without disconnecting from the jabber server. User can still use saved (via cookie/session) jid,sid,rid combination to reconnect with previously opened session. However, bosh connection manager will drop the connection after "X" seconds of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP does not say anything about having or not a *timeout*. So, in theory, you XMPP Session could last as long as the TCP connection is established.

You are free to implement a *timeout* in your client or server though...

Comment: But using JIDs with RIDs if the connection is terminated shouldn't you be still be able to connect to the same session?